# trouble setting default values in a function[r]

Tags: r, function, error-checking

Info:

- I am working in R with the state information package "state.x77"

Goal:

- I am finding correlations between the independent variables and the dependent "Life expectancy".

Issue with code:

- I want to set a default value for the method. the below code works just fine. But, of course I can't use the "spearman" or "kendall" methods.

```
cor_v1_v2 = function(v1, v2 = state.x77[,"Life Exp"], method = "pearson"){
  cor(v1,v2,method = "pearson")
}
```

I have tried several variants such as:

```
cor_v1_v2 = function(v1, v2 = state.x77[,"Life Exp"], method = "input"){
  cor(v1,v2,method = "input")
}
```

and:

```
cor_v1_v2 = function(v1, v2 = state.x77[,"Life Exp"], method = "pearson"){
  cor(v1,v2,method)
}
```

I get return use errors for each. I know it's just my syntax and my thinking but I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want

```r
cor_v1_v2 = function(v1, v2 = state.x77[,"Life Exp"], method = "pearson"){
  cor(v1, v2, method = method)
}
```

This will default to "pearson" but is changeable to whatever you want.

Comment: of course. Method will put the string in the "Method ="

Thank you so Much Allan.